# pots API [object object ] in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native

I had a problem sending data to the server.
when I try to submit data via postman successfully with the response below
and if I activate
'Content-Type': 'application / json'

i have a problem that is
JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "success login",
    "id_kurir": "3",
    "username": "tester",
}
```

When I try with code, I get an error that is [object object]

this my code :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Uname : '',
      Upass : ''
    }
  }

  login= ()=>{
    const {Uname,Upass} = this.state;
    fetch('https://example.com/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      // headers: {
      //   'Accept' : 'application/json',
      //   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      //},
              body: JSON.stringify({
              username: Uname,
              password: Upass
            })
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
          alert(responseJson);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
        }).catch((error)=>{
          console.log(error);
        })
      Keyboard.dismiss();
  }



           <Form style={styles.mainForm}>
              <Item style={styles.formItems}>
                <Input placeholder="Username" style={styles.Input} onChangeText={Uname => this.setState({Uname})}/>
              </Item>
              <Item style={styles.formItems}>
              <Input style={styles.Input} secureTextEntry={true} onChangeText={(Upass) => this.setState({Upass})}/>
              </Item>

              <View style={styles.Button}>
                {/* <Button block style={styles.mainBtn} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('home')}> */}
                <Button block info style={styles.mainBtn} onPress={this.login}>
                  <Text style={styles.btnText}>Submit</Text>
                </Button>
              </View>
            </Form>
```

where is the fault?

Comment: Try alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson)); because alerts can not show objects.

Comment: done, I have filled in the username and password correctly, but why was the response not found? even though I've tried using Postman to fill in the username and password correctly and the results are appropriate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server probably a 404 or 500 error. Instead of response.json() use response.text() you will get the html in text.

I assume Your server is not taking JSON formatted body

Try using below code.

**Option 1:**

```
fetch('https://example.com/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        username: Uname,
        password: Upass
    })
}).then(response => response.text()).then((text) => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '').replace(/[\u0080-\uFFFF]/g, ''); 
    // If android, remove unwanted chars. 
  }
  return text;
}).then(response => JSON.parse(response));
```

**Option 2:**

```
fetch('https://example.com/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        username: Uname,
        password: Upass
    })
}).then((response) => response.text()).then((responseJson) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
}).catch((error) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    console.log(error);
})
```

Comment: I tried using the second option

But after the console response [object object]

Comment: ow turns out ... you don't have permission to access / on this server ,

Comment: It's issue at your server side, try fixing it and retry with normal fetch call you will get your response.